# I feel like a rat in a pipe factory. Strategy for designing WPF binding solutions?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

So many dead ends!

I'm trying to achieve two way binding between a visualization and an array of about 300 single bytes of data.

It sounds simple but it turns out not.

Even Bea Stollnitz, it seems, took three goes at binding a polyline to data:
[Part 1](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=35)   [Part 2](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=36)  [Part 3](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=37)

What hope does a beginner have?

So my question is:

**Is there a series of systematic questions you ask yourself which helps avoiding dead ends and wasted time when coming up with a binding strategy in WPF?**

(Or is there a link to a concise document/matrix that tells you what you need to implement in order to reach the cheese?)

Comment: +1 for I feel like a rat in a pipe factory.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the MSDN [data-binding overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) is really helpful. It gives you diagrams, code examples, implementation details- the whole nine yards. It is truly exhaustive but if you spend an hour or two poring over it you will leave with a much better idea of what is happening.

Also, [this tutorial](http://coredotnet.blogspot.com/2006/05/wpf-data-binding-tutorial.html) from core.net is more concise but very helpful in that it is approach-based. He basically breaks down data-binding from three approaches:

1. Typical
2. C# Only
3. C# and XAML

Answer (score 0):

[IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) is your probably your best friend. You can use it for all kinds of data conversion, from and to your binding source!

So bind to your data and use a IValueConverter implementation to do your conversion stuff!